# Angular Reactive Form: Setting/Patching Value for Nested Forms

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a form structure similar to this:

```
itemEntities: [
   {customisable: [{food: {..}, quantity: 1}, {food: {..}, quantity: 5}]},       
   {customisable: [{food: {..}, quantity: 0}]}, 
]
```

I am trying to setValue/patchValue with new quantity values. I had initialized the quantity with value of 0.

However, when I try to pass in a variable like

```
this.toggleForm.controls.itemEntities.controls[i]
    .controls.customisable.controls[j].controls.quantity.setValue(quantity);
```

quantity always evaluates to 0 within setValue. I tried to console.log out quantity before attempting to set the value, and it returns me the correct value. Also, checking the typeof quantity says that quantity is a number. Somehow, if i try to .setValue(5) i.e. use a number instead of a variable name, it manages to set the value on the form correctly.

Any suggestions on how to set the value correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Set Value**

It is necessary to mention **all the controls** inside the method. If this is not done, it will throw an error.

**Patch Value**

You can also set a single value

You should use `.patchValue` as

**`formgroup.patchValue({quantity:quantity});`**

Comment: Despite trying patchValue to change the value of only quantity, it still doesn't work. I.e. .patchValue(5) works, .patchValue(quantity) doesn't work.

Comment: @MINS Use `.patchValue` like this. i.e. patchValue({quantity: 5})

Comment: this overrides the value to become an object. ie. quantity: {quantity: 5}

Comment: Anyway, i just tried casting the values because my previous code throws an AbstractControl issue.

Comment: the strange thing is that even if i use patchValue({quantity: option.quantity}), this causes the value to become quantity: {quantity: 0} which is the same problem i faced. which is my option.quantity not being evaluated correctly

Comment: if you have an ArrayForm use "at" https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#at. some like: ((this.toggleForm.get('itemEntities') as FormArray).at(i).get('customisable') as FormArray).at(j).get('quantity').setValue(quantity)